# How to transfer databases and site contents

Tags: database, web-services

I own a website with 20 GB data on it Now I decided to change the Hosting compnay .
I'm Moving to Russian VPS so is there a way to transfer the contents of my website to the Russian VPS without uploading them again .

Is there a service that does this.
I heard that there is a way to do this using shell access (BUT what is shell access and how it works) 
thanx in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log in to one of your old host using an SSH connection, then connect from there to your new host, again using an SSH connection, and then upload all files from your first server to the second. For databases, do a data dump on your first server, and through the SSH connection, run the data dump against a database on your new server.

Depending on the hosts, how you connect via SSH will differ, but there should be instruction available from the providers. If you can't find the directions, just e-mail the provider's support and ask.

Comment: No problem, just went through doing this myself last week, and that's how I ended up doing the data migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server itself, you can ftp into your old site from the new server, and download all the data from the new server, without having to download to a personal computer.

Answer (score 0):

If your current provider supports FTP, you can issue FTP commands from your new VPS to the current FTP site. If your data is in DB - backup and transfer backup.

You can't avoid 40Gb of transfer (20 out from old site and 20 in new one).

This is one of the reasons that makes Amazon S3 a good thing.